# Expand rows per group while changing only one variable

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
library(tibble)

test <- tibble(
  id = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3),
  time = rep(2000:2002, times = 2),
  value = c(2, 1, 10, 4, 3, 6)
)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  id     time value
  <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 A      2000     2
2 A      2001     1
3 A      2002    10
4 B      2000     4
5 B      2001     3
6 B      2002     6
```

For each id, I want to expand the time period back to 1995. The value from 1995 to 2000 will stay the same, the only thing that must change is the year. Here's the expected output:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
   id     time value
   <chr> <int> <dbl>
 1 A      1995     2
 2 A      1996     2
 3 A      1997     2
 4 A      1998     2
 5 A      1999     2
 6 A      2000     2
 7 A      2001     1
 8 A      2002    10
 9 B      1995     4
10 B      1996     4
11 B      1997     4
12 B      1998     4
13 B      1999     4
14 B      2000     4
15 B      2001     3
16 B      2002     6
```

How can I do that? (if possible in tidyverse style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `complete` to create rows for `time` from 1995 to `max` `time` value  for each `id` and `fill` the `NA` values with latest value available.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  complete(time = 1995:max(time)) %>%
  fill(value, .direction = 'up')

#   id     time value
#   <chr> <int> <dbl>
# 1 A      1995     2
# 2 A      1996     2
# 3 A      1997     2
# 4 A      1998     2
# 5 A      1999     2
# 6 A      2000     2
# 7 A      2001     1
# 8 A      2002    10
# 9 B      1995     4
#10 B      1996     4
#11 B      1997     4
#12 B      1998     4
#13 B      1999     4
#14 B      2000     4
#15 B      2001     3
#16 B      2002     6
```

Answer (score 3):

a `data.table` approach

```
library( data.table )
setDT(test)
#create all combinations of id and year
DT <- CJ( id = unique( test$id ), time = 1995:2002 )
#rolling join value by ID and time (roll to nearest time in test)
DT[, value := test[DT, value, roll = "nearest", on = .(id, time) ] ]

#     id time value
#  1:  A 1995     2
#  2:  A 1996     2
#  3:  A 1997     2
#  4:  A 1998     2
#  5:  A 1999     2
#  6:  A 2000     2
#  7:  A 2001     1
#  8:  A 2002    10
#  9:  B 1995     4
# 10:  B 1996     4
# 11:  B 1997     4
# 12:  B 1998     4
# 13:  B 1999     4
# 14:  B 2000     4
# 15:  B 2001     3
# 16:  B 2002     6
```

Comment: replaced original answer with a rolling join, which is more suitable here...